# Как оптимизировать и переиспользовать код на Python?

Tags: python, telebot

Я только начала ботов писать. можно ли как-то повторяющиеся кусочки кода записать в отдельный файл? просто из-за них код выйдет на более 3000 строк

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('....')



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите /train, чтобы начать тренироваться \nВведите /start для перезапуска')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['train'])
def train(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    word1 = types.KeyboardButton('аэропОрты')
    word2 = types.KeyboardButton('аэропортЫ')
    markup.add(word1, word2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите слово с правильным ударением:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        # начинаем отслеживать 1 вопрос
        if message.text == 'аэропОрты':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно ✅')
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            word1 = types.KeyboardButton('бАнты')
            word2 = types.KeyboardButton('бантЫ')
            markup.add(word1, word2)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите слово с правильным ударением:', reply_markup=markup)

        elif message.text == 'аэропортЫ':
            a = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Неверно ❌ \nПравильный ответ: аэропОрты \nНажмите /train, чтобы начать заново.", reply_markup=a)
```

Comment: вот таких кусочков мне нужно около 250, наверное, можно было и компактнее писать, но не знаю как

Comment: и можно ли половину кода оставить в одном файле, а в другом остальное перенести?

Comment: можно, все что повторяете выносите в данные, данные в файл конфига можно, а вообще если речь про варианты слов неплохо бы применить `регулярные выражения`, если это тест то удобно сформировать `json` с вопросами и ответами

Comment: обязательно дополните вопрос подробностями, как формируется Ваш код через кнопку `Править` под вопросом, в заголовке  вопроса не стоит писать лишнее — только суть, в самом вопросе подробности, но без долгих историй.

Comment: Вам стоит использовать другую библиотеку, на `telebot` ботов не пишут. Стоить разделить логику на разные файлы, хендлеры в одном, клавиатуры в другом, вынести повторяющуюся логику в функции